# error: cannot assign a value to final variable (int)

Tags: java, final

Ok I'm sure this is simple, but I'm having issues and my mind is blank. =(
I know 'final' makes it so the variable can't change but that's pretty much all I can figure out about it right now.
And the code...

If I take out the 'final' the error comes up as "error: missing return statement
      }" for the first two methods.

EDIT: Thank you all for the help, surprising how fast I got help!
So I just took out 'final' and added 'void' to the first two methods. I'm sure it'll take some time to fully understand everything, but it definitely helps.

There is a part two and here is the part that I have no clue on what to do...
The second part you just have to test this first program. Am I supposed to make a separate file with the same code?
If anyone can help great, but if not thats fine I'll work on it later.

Comment: Neither of those variables should be final, since they're going to be incremented/decremented. Why are you trying to make them final?

Comment: Also, numberInRoom should not be static, since that is a variable which will be different for each room. totalNumber being static makes sense.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a class given the format, so I'm going to suggest you get some help with your teacher to understand the correct usage of `static` and what it means. There are a number of things wrong with this code segment that suggest you mind want to spend a little more time on it ;)

Comment: For your second part, you need to look into JUnit (it's a java framework) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You declare your function as

```
  public static int removeOneFromRoom (int number)
  {
     totalNumber = totalNumber-number;
  }
```

The emphasis here is the public static int, telling the compiler that your function is supposed to return an integer. You do however not return anything in that function body, so the compiler complains rightfully. Either return something, or declare the return value as void.

Comment: +1, just so the OP knows (as I sense you're a beginner), removing `final` isn't causing another error, it's just that with `final` incorrectly used, the compiler doesn't even _get_ to the the error with the missing return statement. Sometimes the error you get isn't the only error, but just the first ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing the return statement for the first two methods. Or you may want to change the return type to void if you don't need to return anything.

Doing these will remove your error but it might differ from what you need.

```
  public static void addOneToRoom(int number)
  {
     numberInRoom = numberInRoom+number;
  }

  public static void removeOneFromRoom (int number)
  {
     totalNumber = totalNumber-number;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared with **`static`** and **`final`** keywords behaves like a constant. But what does that mean ?

> It means you can't change their values. In simpler terms if variable is a primitive then you can't change its value but if its a reference variable then you can't change the reference to some other address.

So in your code, declaring **`numberInRoom`** and  **`totalNumber`** variables as **`static`** and **`final`** is wrong

```
public static int numberInRoom=3;
public static int totalNumber=30;

public static int addOneToRoom(int number)
{
   numberInRoom = numberInRoom+number;
}

public static int removeOneFromRoom (int number)
{
   totalNumber = totalNumber-number;
}
```

Are you sure that you want these variables to be declared as **`static`** because such variables shall be shared by all instances of the concerned class. Please have a look at what does declaring variables as [**`static`** and **`final`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) means